# How to use variables in WHERE clause for a SQL SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, where-clause

My SQL SELECT query has 3 variables set by a HTML form, however these variables can be null:

```
   $suburb = (isset($_POST['suburb'])) ? $_POST['suburb'] : '';
   $postcode = (isset($_POST['postcode'])) ? $_POST['postcode'] : '';
   $state = (isset($_POST['state'])) ? $_POST['state'] : '';
```

When all 3 variables are entered in the form the SELECT query processes fine (due to the AND's in the WHERE clause). But when one or more variables are blank, the SELECT query errors as it is looking for a NULL value in the databse.

What I want it to do is when a variable is null, I don't want a where clause for it

Query:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    cs.customerRefId,
    cc.firstName,
    cc.lastName,
    cc.email,
    cc.phone,
    cc.mobile,
    cs.seekingAddressSuburb, 
    cs.seekingAddressPostcode, 
    cs.seekingAddressState
FROM 
    customer_seeking cs
LEFT JOIN
    customer_contact cc ON cc.customerRefId = cs.customerRefId
WHERE
cs.seekingAddressSuburb = '$suburb' AND
cs.seekingAddressPostcode = '$postcode' AND
cs.seekingAddressState = '$state'
SQL;  


if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
```

For example if only the state variable is defined (cs.seekingAddressSuburb = '$suburb' AND
cs.seekingAddressPostcode = '$postcode' AND are removed from the WHERE clause):

```
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT 
    cs.customerRefId,
    cc.firstName,
    cc.lastName,
    cc.email,
    cc.phone,
    cc.mobile,
    cs.seekingAddressSuburb, 
    cs.seekingAddressPostcode, 
    cs.seekingAddressState
FROM 
    customer_seeking cs
LEFT JOIN
    customer_contact cc ON cc.customerRefId = cs.customerRefId
WHERE
cs.seekingAddressState = '$state'
SQL;
```

Comment: check if empty if so, don't add the and

Comment: Is it not best practice to put if statements in a SQL query?

Comment: You should use prepared statements, otherwise you are vulnerable to SQL injections, such as passing in `'; drop table customer_seeking;'` for `$state`

Comment: Yes, I need to go through my code a fix up a few things, but I just want to get it working to start off with :)

Comment: What class are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

construct your query in a String then add one by one if each field have value. example :

```
$query = "select * from table1 where 1=1";
if(!empty($suburb)) $query.=" and cs.seekingAddressSuburb = '$suburb'";
if(!empty($postcode)) $query.=" and cs.seekingAddressPostcode = '$postcode'";
if(!empty($state)) $query.=" and cs.seekingAddressState = '$state'";
//run your query then
```

Comment: You should be using `pdo` or `mysqli` and use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want to do but you try this code in **[PHP FIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/)**

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$c;

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = $a". (!empty($b) ? ' AND b ='. $b: '')  ." ". (!empty($c) ? 'AND C ='. $c: '');

echo $SQL;
```

**TO RELATE IN YOUR CODE**

```
$suburb = if(isset($_POST['suburb']));
$postcode = if(isset($_POST['postcode']));
$state = if(isset($_POST['state']));

$SQL = "SELECT cs.customerRefId,
cc.firstName,
cc.lastName,
cc.email,
cc.phone,
cc.mobile,
cs.seekingAddressSuburb, 
cs.seekingAddressPostcode, 
cs.seekingAddressState
FROM 
    customer_seeking cs
LEFT JOIN
    customer_contact cc ON cc.customerRefId = cs.customerRefId WHERE cs.seekingAddressSuburb = $suburb". (!empty($postcode) ? ' AND cs.seekingAddressPostcode ='. $postcode: '')  ." ". (!empty($state) ? 'AND cs.seekingAddressState ='. $state: '');

echo $SQL;
```

Comment: This kinda seems to work, but if $suburb is blank to there is an error. Should I add (!empty($suburb) ? 'AND cs.seekingAddressSuburb ='. $suburb: '')

Comment: yes, you can try also that one. just be sure that there is **at least 1** variable that has a value

Comment: All 3 can be blank though, how can I do that?