# php if else check inside a string

Tags: php, ajax

Im trying to squeeze few `html` codes and `php` codes into a string. (And then pass the string back to ajax callback and ajax prints the string).

This is my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pfilter WHERE id = '$getId'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $output_string =    '<table>';
    $output_string .=   '<tr><td>Make</td><td>'.$myrow['make'].'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Model</td><td>'.$myrow['model'].'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Series</td><td>'.$myrow['series'].'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Years</td><td>'.$myrow['years'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

But I want to check whether `$myrow['make']` has any value, and if it does then print that whole `tr`. Otherwise it should skip that whole `tr`. Whats the best way to check this? I tried putting `if else` inside that string using `'. .'` but didnt suceed. Do I have to use `$output_string .=` again and again between `ifelse`? Im new to PHP, Im glad if you guys can help me out here.

Comment: you can refer to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/17015766/2293679 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine length operations with the ternary operator.

```
$output_string .= (strlen($myrow['make']) > 0 ? '<tr><td>Make</td><td>'.$myrow['make'].'</td></tr>' : '');
```

You are simply checking if there is any length to the string, and if so returning the full line with the values. If not, returning an empty string. You can read more about the ternary operator here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is i guess the cleanest way to do this. Thanks agian :)

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that (due at least in part to a mistake in an earlier version of the language), PHP's ternary operator has rather odd associativity and precedence, so it's generally necessary to wrap the expression using it in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator:

```
'text' . (strpos($myrow['make'], 'foo') !== FALSE ? '<tr>...</tr>' : '') . 'more text'
```

Comment: Whatever it is. I don't use PHP anymore. He gets the picture though.

Comment: That's, uh, not really a valid reason for making code half in a different language part of your example.

Comment: I'm not here to write code for him, I'm here to show him how to solve his problem. This shows him how to solve his problem. What if I wrote pseudocode? Would that be completely wrong?

Comment: @GJK Pseudocode is useful if you say you demonstrating a general approach, and that it will require translating into a particular language. Since this is a question specifically about implementing something in PHP, it seems reasonable that answers be valid PHP. (I realise you've edited the answer, just answering your point).

Comment: @GJK Yes, pseudo-code is preferable to incorrect code, especially when helping green programmers.

Answer (score 0):

The ".=" operator concatenates strings together.

This:

```
$output_string =    '<table>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Make</td><td>'.$myrow['make'].'</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>Model</td><td>'.$myrow['model'].'</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>Series</td><td>'.$myrow['series'].'</td></tr>
                     <tr><td>Years</td><td>'.$myrow['years'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

is equivalent to this:

```
$output_string =    '<table>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Make</td><td>'.$myrow['make'].'</td></tr>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Model</td><td>'.$myrow['model'].'</td></tr>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Series</td><td>'.$myrow['series'].'</td></tr>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Years</td><td>'.$myrow['years'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

So put your logic like this:

```
$output_string =    '<table>';
if (@$myrow['make']) {
    $output_string .=   '<tr><td>Make</td><td>'.$myrow['make'].'</td></tr>';
}
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Model</td><td>'.$myrow['model'].'</td></tr>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Series</td><td>'.$myrow['series'].'</td></tr>';
$output_string .=   '<tr><td>Years</td><td>'.$myrow['years'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use the ternary operator inside a string. So, here it goes:

```
$output_string .=   (!empty($myrow['make'])?'<tr><td>Make</td><td>'.$myrow['make'].'</td></tr>
                       : '' )
                    <tr><td>Model</td><td>'.$myrow['model'].'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Series</td><td>'.$myrow['series'].'</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Years</td><td>'.$myrow['years'].'</td></tr></table>';
```

Enclosing the condition by parentheses will do the trick.